# nxhtml mode support

Tags: major-mode, emacs24.4

I've been using https://stackoverflow.com/a/17761144/788700 to get multiple major modes in rst-mode. It has been working in Emacs 24.3. However as emacs develops the same code gradually stops working.

Here's emacs-24.3:

[image]

as I go from rst-mode chunk to py-mode chunk emacs switches the major mode.

In emacs-24.5 it doesn't work automatically anymore, but one can make emacs to switch mode locally by issuing new line:

[image]

(same behaviour in emacs-24.4)

In emacs-25.0.5 it doesn't work at all:

[image]

only syntax highlighting works, but modes doesn't switch as I go from one chunk to another.

Here's minimal configuration which reproduces the issue:

- `.emacs`:

  ```
  (load "~/.emacs.d/misc/nxhtml/autostart.el")
  (require 'mumamo)
  (require 'mumamo-fun)
  ```
- [.emacs.d.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61989972/misc/.emacs.d-with-nxhtml.zip) (which contains only nxhtml + defuns from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17761144/788700 in `mumamo-fun.el`. nxhtml mode site went offline, and author doesn't seem to be present in the Internet)

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of nXhtml. Unfortunately I do not have time to fix this.

If someone want to try to fix it I would be glad to answer questions and support the effort though.